# ASP.NET custom control rendering before <%= %> code executes to populate property

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls

I have a custom control that exposes a property.  When I set it using a fixed value, everything works correctly.  But if I try to set its value using the <%= %> tags, it goes a little whacky:

```
<cc:CustomControl ID="CustomControl" runat="server" Property1='<%= MyProperty %>' />
<%= MyProperty %>
```

When this gets rendered, the <%= MyProperty %> tag underneat the custom control is rendered as I expect (with the value of MyProperty).  However, when I step into the Render function of the CustomControl, the value for Property1 is literally the string "<%= MyProperty %>" instead of the actual underlying value of MyProperty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You control is initialized from the markup during `OnInit`.  So if that syntax worked, it wouldn't have the effect you wanted anyway, since `MyProperty` would be evaluated during `OnInit` and not at render time (like it is with the second usage).

You want to use the data binding syntax instead:

```
<cc:CustomControl ID="CustomControl" runat="server" Property1='<%# MyProperty %>' />
```

Just make sure to call `DataBind()` on the container (Page, UserControl, etc).

Alternatively, you can set the property in your code behind:

```
CustomControl.Property1 = MyProperty;
```

Comment: Is there no better answer to this?  I use the <%= MyProperty %> syntax with MS controls all the time.  Should not there be a way to do the same with custom controls.

Comment: How are you using that syntax with MS controls?

Answer (score 1):

Try <%# MyProperty %> in the CustomControl and see if that works.